# Wanted: a graph $G$ without bridges, whose square is not hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory

Construct an example of graph $G$ without bridges, such that its square $G^2$ is non hamiltonian.
Note:
Since Fleischner's Theorem (the square of each 2-connected graph is Hamiltonian) and bridges are forbidden, the required graph should have at least one cut-vertex.

Comment: Please see http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot

Comment: Or, if this is not homework/coursework, see http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask

Comment: No, the teacher said that this example exists, but he did not remember it. He also said, that as conclusion we obtain that the Fleischner's Theorem does not improve.


Comment: I tried to find information on the Internet, but had no success

Comment: Perhaps you should ask your teacher, and post an answer here?

Comment: In this context the square of a graph $G$ has the same vertices but has edges between vertices if their distance in $G$ is 1 or 2. 

Comment: The old help center links mentioned in the comments above are now broken (but archived on the Wayback Machine [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101124203624/http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101124212144/http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask), respectively). The equivalent pages in the help center today are '[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://mathoverflow.net/help/dont-ask)' and '[How do I ask a good question?](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-ask)', respectively.

Answer (score 10):

You can find an example of a bridgeless graph with cut points, whose square is not hamiltonian in this [paper](https://eudml.org/doc/177584) of Fleischner and Kronk. (I know the paper is in German, but the figure of the graph is on the first page.) Fleischner also mentions this example in his paper "[The Square of Every Two-Connected Graph Is Hamiltonian](https://doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(74)90091-4)".